# Alternative to hook into RTE javascript

Tags: javascript, publishing-page, rich-text

I'm looking to add some logic when a HTML element (input, button, .. but no regular text) is clicked inside the RTE control on a publishing page. One of the solutions I've been thinking about is [hooking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/789630/javascript-function-hooks) into the RTE javascript right after the spot where the selection has been set (visible in the UI on HTML elements).

Are there other (cleaner) alternatives?
I'm not sure where RTE.Cursor.$Ez_0 is coupled to the click event (this seems to be the entry point).

Comment: What version of SharePoint is this? But as a preliminary answer you either provide an override page or hook into the JS function (Your presumption) these would be the best approaches.

Comment: As Hugh said depends on the version you have. Are you creating the input and button in the RTE directly ?
Will like to embed a form in the RTE?